# Redirect 404 server errors in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, iis-8

Is there a way to redirect from "The resource cannot be found" error page to some other page (i.e. Home)?

I tried redirecting from error pages under IIS Manager, but this works only partially for me: if I try to access incorrect Http resource, application throws an exception "Server Error in '/' Application". For example:

https://somesite/Home/Show/NonExistingData - redirect works

https://somesite/NonExistingReource - does not work

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that exception is thrown by ASP.NET application and this could be redirected to some other page by providing customErrors redirect in web.config like the following:

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
    <error redirect="https://somesite/Home/Index" statusCode="404" />
</customErrors>
```